# Improving build process Maven and SVN

Tags: java, maven, svn, optimization

I have to improve the build process in a project that I am currently working on. There are several sub projects in the main project. We currently use maven(2.1) as a build tool and svn  for version control. It takes around one and a half hours to do a Java build let alone packaging and deploying (another one hour). The main bottle neck I found in the build process is the phase where all the code is checked out which takes around 30-40 mins. Is there a better way of doing this? Is there any other way in which the builds can be run parallely for sub-projects?  Also the packaging and the installation tools are written in JAVA. Is there any better option to this to increase the performance? Any ideas will be very helpful.

Note:Changing the underlying version control is not possible now that will require approvals up the management hierarchy.

Comment: that seems like an incredibly long time to be checking things out of svn... do you have a large amount of binary files in the repository(ies)?  Are there ways you can split up the builds so there are many happening in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

- update mvn to latest available (3.1-release)
- don't check out whole source each time, do `svn update` instead (it will save lots of time here)
- try enabling [multi threaded build](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3) (it will optimize actual build time by ~ 40%)
- configure [surefire to run on multiple jvm](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html) (it will also optimize time if you have lots of time spent in surefire execution)
- get better hardware

---

also vote and watch http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5523

Comment: Jigar I have not given you a down vote. Some of ideas you have given  are valid but I have already looked into them, also switching to maven 3.1 release can be done but I think enabling parallel builds in this release is still not stable so cant take a chance.

Comment: I have been using it for long time its pretty stable